# Trying to install ionCube Loader on Easyphp Devserver 16.1

Tags: php, apache, easyphp, ioncube

I need to install ioncube loader on my local machine with easyphp 16.1 (apache 2.4.28 and php 5.6.17).

I've followed the instructions of the loader_wizard.php and modified the php.ini file:

[my php.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLKQr.jpg)

But when I start the apache server, I notice that php.ini has been modified and the ioncube line has been replaced with a xdebug line:

[modified php.ini after server start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15qK2.jpg)

I also tried to create a php.ini that call the ioncube loader in the same folder of the php files I need to open, without success.

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If your php.ini gets altered when you restart the server software, it's likely that the startup process is creating the php.ini file from a template or partial php.ini file fragments somewhere. Check documentation for EasyPHP or post a support query with them to find out how to make a permanent change to the php.ini file.